# need to check if int is a single word before converting

Tags: regex, perl

i am converting int to int32_t in a C file.

To check whether its int and not any word i convert "int "(one space after int) to "int32_t "

MY CODE

```
open(FILE, $input) or die $!;
my @lines = <FILE>;

foreach(@lines) {   
        $_ =~ s/int /int32_t /g;    # int to int32_t
        print $_;
}
```

If input C file has line as

```
print abcd;
```

Then It gets converted to print32_t too.

How do i exclude such cases. Which means i need to check whether some letter precedes before 'int' or I need to check if int is a single word

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `\b` zero-width assertion for word-boundaries in your regex.

```
foreach (@lines) {   
        s/\bint\b/int32_t/g;    # int to int32_t
        print;
}
```

[Perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) describes them like this:

> A word boundary (`\b` ) is a spot between two characters that has a `\w`
>   on one side of it and a `\W` on the other side of it (in either order),
>   counting the imaginary characters off the beginning and end of the
>   string as matching a `\W` . (Within character classes `\b` represents
>   backspace rather than a word boundary, just as it normally does in any
>   double-quoted string.)

Comment: @Ad-vic: I have already explained this in your previous question. Please read the answers you get, as people are using their own personal time to help you out.